# Why do some datapoints show up as 1e-16? Can I hide them from the plot?

Tags: python, graph, jupyter-notebook, scientific-computing

I would like to know why some of the datapoints showing up at 1e-16 and how to adjust the plot to hide these datapoints.

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

And the variable f4 is:

```py
def f4(x):
    if x>0.125 and x<0.125+1/3:
        return 1
    return 0
```

Then rightrs and midpoint function:

```py
def rightrs (f, a, b, n):
    h = (b-a)/n
    s = 0.
    x = a + h
    for i in range (n):
        s += f(x)
        x += h
    return s * h

def midpoint (f, a, b, n):
    h = (b-a)/n
    s = 0.
    x = a + h/2.
    for i in range(n):
        s += f(x)
        x += h
    return s*h
```

Finally I graphed it with the following code:

```
ns = np.arange (1, 1000)
error_midpoint = np.zeros(len(ns))
error_rightrs = np.zeros(len(ns))
for i in range(len(ns)):
    error_midpoint[i] = midpoint(f4, 0, 2, ns[i]) - 1./3.
    error_rightrs[i]= rightrs(f4, 0, 2, ns[i]) - 1./3.
h = 2./ns
plt.loglog(h, error_rightrs, ".")
plt.loglog(h, error_midpoint, ".")
```

And here is the graph:

[image: Graph]

Could someone tell me why some of the datapoints are showing up at 1e-16 and how to adjust the plot to hide these datapoints?

Comment: I made some speculative edits to fix obvious indentation errors, but I had to guess what was broken; please review. It is a syntax error in Python to break your indentation - please take care to post exactly the code you need help with (on the desktop version of this site, paste your code, select it, and type ctrl-K to format it correctly).

Comment: Here you can see the value: https://wandbox.org/permlink/LlF8s8kss0QQLR6d Many values are in the range of 10^-17 and 10^-16

Answer (score 0):

Some datapoints show up at 1e-16, because thats what their values are. You can hide them by setting an appropriate limit on your y axis in the plot. Try `plt.ylim`.

Extra comments:

Errors should be computed using absolute values or norms.

For these types of convergence test you should choose `n` on a log scale, i.e., 1,2,4,8,16,... .